# Merge multiple Excel sheets into one sheet

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I'm using [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet) to process some Excel files, now I need to combine them into one file with one sheet.
I know how to do [sheets copying](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/excel-sheet-copy-delete/111), but that will result in multiple sheets. What I need is a single output sheet that will contain all of them, one after another.

Currently what I'm doing is I export each sheet as a `DataTable` and then import it one by one:

```cs
string[] files = { "Book1.xlsx", "Book2.xlsx", "Book3.xlsx" };

var destination = new ExcelFile();
var destinationSheet = destination.Worksheets.Add("Sheets");
int startRow = 0;

foreach (string file in files)
{
    var source = ExcelFile.Load(file);
    foreach (var sourceSheet in source.Worksheets)
    {
        var table = sourceSheet.CreateDataTable(new CreateDataTableOptions());
        destinationSheet.InsertDataTable(table, new InsertDataTableOptions() { StartRow = startRow });
        startRow += table.Rows.Count;
    }
}

destination.Save("Merged Output.xlsx");
```

But with this, I lose the cell styles and text formatting.
Is there any way to preserve the style with `DataTable`?

Comment: Searching on here will give you lots of possibilities, this is one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike that code uses Excel Interop, I can't use that.

Comment: "that code uses Excel Interop" ? what do you men here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT (2022-10-28):**

In the current latest version of GemBox.Spreadsheet there is another set of `CellRange.CopyTo()` overload methods that accept the `CopyOptions` parameter with which you can specify what you want to copy.

For example, you could specify that you want column widths and row heights to be copied as well, like this:

```cs
range.CopyTo(destinationSheet, destinationSheet.Rows.Count, 0,
    new CopyOptions() { CopyTypes = CopyTypes.Default | CopyTypes.ColumnWidths | CopyTypes.RowHeights });
```

**ORIGINAL:**

For this you can use [`CellRange.CopyTo`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/docs/GemBox.Spreadsheet.CellRange.html#GemBox_Spreadsheet_CellRange_CopyTo_) method, like the following:

```cs
string[] files = { "Book1.xlsx", "Book2.xlsx", "Book3.xlsx" };

var destination = new ExcelFile();
var destinationSheet = destination.Worksheets.Add("Sheets");

foreach (string file in files)
{
    var source = ExcelFile.Load(file);
    foreach (var sourceSheet in source.Worksheets)
    {
        var range = sourceSheet.GetUsedCellRange(true);
        range.CopyTo(destinationSheet, destinationSheet.Rows.Count, 0);
    }
}

destination.Save("Merged Output.xlsx");
```

Note that `CopyTo` will just copy the value and style of the cells.

But if needed, you can use something like this to copy the column widths and row heights as well.

```cs
string[] files = { "Book1.xlsx", "Book2.xlsx", "Book3.xlsx" };

var destination = new ExcelFile();
var destinationSheet = destination.Worksheets.Add("Sheets");

int lastColumn = 0;
foreach (string file in files)
{
    var source = ExcelFile.Load(file);
    foreach (var sourceSheet in source.Worksheets)
    {
        var range = sourceSheet.GetUsedCellRange(true);
        int startRow = destinationSheet.Rows.Count;
        range.CopyTo(destinationSheet, startRow, 0);

        for (int r = 0; r < range.Height; r++)
            destinationSheet.Rows[r + startRow].Height = sourceSheet.Rows[r].Height;

        for (; lastColumn < range.Width; lastColumn++)
            destinationSheet.Columns[lastColumn].Width = sourceSheet.Columns[lastColumn].Width;
    }
}

destination.Save("Merged Output.xlsx");
```

Also if needed, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64691354/2699178) to copy the images as well.

You can use that same solution to copy shapes and charts as well, they all have that `Position` property that you need to adjust after copying.